# Site logo is not clickable

Tags: logo

I am using an image as my site logo, and the image displays fine on the site. However, while the image is inside of an 'a' tag, its not clickable. Here's my code:

```
<div class="site-branding">
   <a href="<?php echo bloginfo('url'); ?>">
      <img class="site-logo img-responsive" src="<?php echo bloginfo('url'); ?>/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/logo-height-150.png" />
   </a>
   <img class="description-n-landscape img-responsive" src="<?php echo bloginfo('url'); ?>/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/description-n-landscape.png">

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you try with this code? Because `bloginfo()` [does already `echo`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-includes/general-template.php#L578), you need to remove the `echo`.

```
<div class="site-branding">
   <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>">
      <img class="site-logo img-responsive" src="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/logo-height-150.png" />
   </a>
   <img class="description-n-landscape img-responsive" src="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/description-n-landscape.png" />

</div>
```

Comment: I removed the 'echo', and from the source of the page in my browser, I can see that the <a> tag is correctly putting out the URL. However, that did not change the status of the logo not being clickable... still bewildered.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`home_url()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/home_url) function for your `href` and don't forget to sanitize the URL, when putting it into tag attributes like `href`, with [`esc_url()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_url).

```
<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>
```

Comment: Do you know that your site has been hacked?

Comment: Yup I know, it's an old site I don't use anymore. I just changed my info to my current site. But I am going to take down the hacked site soon anyway. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Probably better, unless you want to be associated with fundamentalist Islamic forces.

Answer (score 1):

Because `bloginfo()` [does already `echo`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-includes/general-template.php#L578), you need to remove `echo` from your posted snippet, making the href `<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>`.

Answer (score 0):

Just Change

```
<a href="<?php echo bloginfo('url'); ?>">
```

to

```
<a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>">
```

That's all. I am sure this will work.